# Can a light block/reduce another light if projected in exact opposite direction?

Tags: visible-light, glass

For my project, I want to block a light passing through clear window glass temporarily, without manual work and without a curtain etc, want to be able to see through the glass, unobstructed if possible, what options do I have?

Comment: Try looking into liquid crystals, and thin films. You could electrically manipulate the liquid crystals for a specific frequency of light, with tight bandwidth. Ideally, it would look like normal glass, but it would block e.g. a laser light. I used to make something like this in a lab, holographically-formed polymer dispersed liquid crystals (HPDLCs). Not something you could make at home, however.

Comment: Because the wavelength of light is so short, using interference is likely unrealistic as well. We're talking hundreds of nanometers, after all.

Comment: How can you see through the glass unobstructed, if you have blocked the light?

Answer (score 0):

[Smart Glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_glass) is the obvious solution. It turns from transparent to highly translucent when voltage is applied. There's many forms and techniques. I saw this in use in Ottawa, it turned from clear to milky white so you could not see through it at all when a switch was thrown.

As to the subject line - no, that doesn't work. Photons of light do not generally interact with each other in the fashion you're thinking of. This works with sound because in that case the sound is the underlying motion of the air, so if you have a sound that wants to push an air molecule up and apply the same signal down you cancel out, but there's simply no analog of that process with light.